# Does Active Directory Federation Services support OpenID Connect claims provider

Tags: c#, openid-connect, adfs

I know Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) supports adding SAML providers as claims providers. But can AD FS support OpenID Connect (OIDC) providers as claims provider.

If yes, please provide how can we add OpenID Connect provider as claim provider. To be specific, this question is not about adding OpenID Connect relying party in Active Directory Federation Services(ADFS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. this is not currently supported.

One way to do this is to federate ADFS with another IDP (Auth0, Okta etc.) via SAML and then use that IDP to do the OIDC connection.

Answer (score 1):

If i refer to the Microsoft documentation Open Id Connect is supported on the ***ADFS 4.0*** ***(Windows Server 2016 and Later)*** , you will find the link below.

[ADFS / Open Id Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-concepts)

Comment: As I stated in the question, this link talks about integrating client applications to ADFS using OpenID Connect, but ADFS to OIDC provider support is what I am looking for.

Comment: The 'openid.net' webpage:
   "Certified OpenID Connect Implementations" [https://openid.net/developers/certified/]
   also states that >
   "ADFS on Windows Server 2016", is a "Certified OpenID Provider Server/Service".
Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are correct but support is only for OIDC downstream not upstream.